# Problems with spaces in php mails

Tags: php, email, postfix-mta

I am having some serious problem with some e-mail issue.

in short:

1. loading a html template file `fopen`
2. replacing some values, marked like this `%password` with real values `str_replace`
3. sending mail via the following function, where `$content` is the loaded html template file:

public function send($receiver, $subject, $content){

```
    $header = "From:".sender. "\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version:1.0" . "\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8" . "\n";

    $mailText = $content;
    mail($receiver, $subject, stripslashes(iconv('utf-8', 'iso-8859-1', $mailText)) , $header);

}
```

the server is debian with postfix.

The Mail template starts with

```
<html> <body style="background-color: #fff;"> <table border="0"...
```

The thing is, and I cannot reproduce it, that in some cases I can find several spaces in the mail, which I didn't put there. Most problematical are those in the user and password string.

Evering else seems correct! The encoding is ok, the html is accepted, all mails can be delivered ...

*password generation:*

```
public static function create_password($length = 12) {
        $characters = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "k", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "_");
        $password = "";
        for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
            $index = rand(1, count($characters)) -1;
            $password .= $characters[$index];
        }
        $password = str_replace("__","_", $password);
        return $password;
    }
```

**Any Ideas, where to start my search?**

Is it the template, str_replace, the postifix, the client, ... ?

Thanks so far

Comment: So, you're intention is to send some passwords in plain text over the wire? :D

Comment: @mihai todor: it worked out, that it was the best way the normal users can understand it. They get a hint to change there password after the first login.

Comment: OK, I understand, but it's still rather insecure...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start by saving the HTML into a separate file and open that with a browser.

> If you see spaces, it's the HTML.
>
> If it looks fine, the mail gets mangled.

### Mangling

This is often caused because your lines are simply too long and mail servers do funky stuff with lines longer than 80 columns (ancient standards).

To prevent mangling I would suggest the following:

1. Add header `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`.
2. Apply `chunk_split(base64_encode(...))` over the whole e-mail content.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had this same problem but for the `To:` line with multiple email addresses. Here are the technical details.

According to the [PHP docs for `mail()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php): The formatting of this string must comply with » [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html). This is for the `$to` and `$message` parameters.

In particular section: **2.1.1. Line Length Limits**

> There are two limits that this standard places on the number of
> characters in a line. Each line of characters **MUST** be no more than
> 998 characters, and **SHOULD** be no more than 78 characters, excluding
> the CRLF.
>
> The 998 character limit is due to limitations in many
> implementations    which send, receive, or store Internet Message
> Format messages that    simply cannot handle more than 998 characters
> on a line. Receiving    implementations would do well to handle an
> arbitrarily large number    of characters in a line for robustness
> sake. However, there are so    many implementations which (in
> compliance with the transport    requirements of [RFC2821]) do not
> accept messages containing more    than 1000 character including the
> CR and LF per line, it is important    for implementations not to
> create such messages.
>
> The more conservative 78 character recommendation is to accommodate
> the many implementations of user interfaces that display these
> messages which may truncate, or disastrously wrap, the display of
> more than 78 characters per line, in spite of the fact that such
> implementations are non-conformant to the intent of this
> specification (and that of [RFC2821] if they actually cause
> information to be lost). Again, even though this limitation is put on
> messages, it is encumbant upon implementations which display messages
>
> to handle an arbitrarily large number of characters in a line
> (certainly at least up to the 998 character limit) for the sake of
> robustness.

There are multiple ways to overcome this found all over the web.

1. From the PHP docs: `$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");`
2. From [Jack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11054875/1707323): `chunk_split(base64_encode(...))`
3. From experience: `foreach($emails as $email){ $to_email = $email."\n";}`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be exceeding the maximum body line length, when this happens, email clients do strange things such as this. Don't put all your body content on one line, use `\n` to create new lines.

Like this

```
<html>
    <body style="background-color: #fff;">
        <table border="0"...
```

Instead of

```
<html> <body style="background-color: #fff;"> <table border="0"...
```

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
stripslashes(iconv('utf-8', 'iso-8859-1', $mailText));
```

Will product a NOTICE if any of your characters passed is NOT latin (UTF8 encoded)
That means they will be messed up (stop in first non-latin, if any).