# White space added in long URL when sending mail with PHP on hosting server

Tags: php, email

I am sending a mail in PHP. This mail contains a long URL.
If I send this mail from my website running in localhost I receive it with a valid URL.
But if I send the same mail from my website running in hosting server I receive it with a corrupted URL: a space (%20) is added in the middle of the URL.

Here is a sample code I am executing either in localhost or in hosting server:

```
$body = "<table style='width:100%; border-collapse:collapse'><thead><tr style='background:blue; color:white;'><td style='padding:0.5em; font-size:2em;'>Test</td><td style='padding:1em; text-align:right'>Test</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan='2'> this is a test this is a test this is a test </td></tr><tr><td><br/></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'><p>Click <a href='http://www.test.com/test.php?url_parameter_test_1=url_parameter_test_1&url_parameter_test_2=url_parameter_test_2&url_parameter_test_3=url_parameter_test_3&url_parameter_test_4=url_parameter_test_4&url_parameter_test_5=url_parameter_test_5&url_parameter_test_6=url_parameter_test_6&url_parameter_test_7=url_parameter_test_7&url_parameter_test_8=url_parameter_test_8&url_parameter_test_9=url_parameter_test_9&url_parameter_test_10=url_parameter_test_10&url_parameter_test_11=url_parameter_test_11&url_parameter_test_12=url_parameter_test_12&url_parameter_test_13=url_parameter_test_13&url_parameter_test_14=url_parameter_test_14&url_parameter_test_15=url_parameter_test_15&url_parameter_test_16=url_parameter_test_16&url_parameter_test_17=url_parameter_test_17&url_parameter_test_18=url_parameter_test_18&url_parameter_test_19=url_parameter_test_19&url_parameter_test_20=url_parameter_test_20&url_parameter_test_21=url_parameter_test_21'>here</a></p></td></tr></tbody></table>";
$boundary = uniqid('mf');
$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "From: Test <test@mail.com>\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=".$boundary."\r\n";
$message = "\r\n\r\n--".$boundary."\r\n";
$message .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n";
$message .= $body;
$message .= "\r\n\r\n--".$boundary."--";
mail("my_mail@mail.com", "test", $message, $header);
```

And here is the URL I receive in my mail when executed from hosting server (contains a %20 in parameter 15):
    http://www.test.com/test.php?url_parameter_test_1=url_parameter_test_1&url_parameter_test_2=url_parameter_test_2&url_parameter_test_3=url_parameter_test_3&url_parameter_test_4=url_parameter_test_4&url_parameter_test_5=url_parameter_test_5&url_parameter_test_6=url_parameter_test_6&url_parameter_test_7=url_parameter_test_7&url_parameter_test_8=url_parameter_test_8&url_parameter_test_9=url_parameter_test_9&url_parameter_test_10=url_parameter_test_10&url_parameter_test_11=url_parameter_test_11&url_parameter_test_12=url_parameter_test_12&url_parameter_test_13=url_parameter_test_13&url_parameter_test_14=url_parameter_test_14&url%20_parameter_test_15=url_parameter_test_15&url_parameter_test_16=url_parameter_test_16&url_parameter_test_17=url_parameter_test_17&url_parameter_test_18=url_parameter_test_18&url_parameter_test_19=url_parameter_test_19&url_parameter_test_20=url_parameter_test_20&url_parameter_test_21=url_parameter_test_21

Do you have any idea why the URL could be corrupted and what I could do to fix it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Just check if the files are the same. If they are, do a var_dump on the body to check for any weird stuff. Compare the stringlenghts etc.

Comment: I did a var_dump of my body variable and it is ok ; it contains the %20 only  in the mail, not on screen nor in my log...

Comment: Try changing the names of the parameters to something shorter. I'm suspecting you're hitting some sort of limit on the server. Also, recommended max length for an URL is no more than 255 characters, even though there is not a set maximum in the HTTP standard. Max 2000 characters will cater for most browsers, anyway. But try with shorter attribute names. There is no reason to have attribute names like: "url_parameter_test_14", when you can just do "upt14" or even "u14"

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie, I am using long attribute names on purpose to illustrate the problem I am having in production. But in deed if I find no better solution I will have to shorten URL as a workaround

Comment: I finally find the solution in another stackoverflow post : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054746/problems-with-spaces-in-php-mails]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the solution in another stackoverflow post :
[[Problems with spaces in php mails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054746/problems-with-spaces-in-php-mails])

```
$body = "<table style='width:100%; border-collapse:collapse'><thead><tr style='background:blue; color:white;'><td style='padding:0.5em; font-size:2em;'>Test</td><td style='padding:1em; text-align:right'>Test</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td><br/></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'> this is a test this is a test this is a test </td></tr><tr><td><br/></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'><p style='font-size:110%;'>Click <a href='http://www.test.com/test.php?url_parameter_test_1=url_parameter_test_1&url_parameter_test_2=url_parameter_test_2&url_parameter_test_3=url_parameter_test_3&url_parameter_test_4=url_parameter_test_4&url_parameter_test_5=url_parameter_test_5&url_parameter_test_6=url_parameter_test_6&url_parameter_test_7=url_parameter_test_7&url_parameter_test_8=url_parameter_test_8&url_parameter_test_9=url_parameter_test_9&url_parameter_test_10=url_parameter_test_10&url_parameter_test_11=url_parameter_test_11&url_parameter_test_12=url_parameter_test_12&url_parameter_test_13=url_parameter_test_13&url_parameter_test_14=url_parameter_test_14&url_parameter_test_15=url_parameter_test_15&url_parameter_test_16=url_parameter_test_16&url_parameter_test_17=url_parameter_test_17&url_parameter_test_18=url_parameter_test_18&url_parameter_test_19=url_parameter_test_19'>here</a></p></td></tr><tr><td><br/></td></tr></tbody></table>";
$boundary = uniqid('mf');
$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "From: Test <test@mail.com>\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=".$boundary."\r\n";
$message = "\r\n\r\n--".$boundary."\r\n";
$message .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
$message .= chunk_split(base64_encode($body));
mail("my_mail@mail.com", "test", $message, $header);
```